# How can I create a start screen for my java game?

Tags: java, applet

How can I make my applet so it goes to a start page and then to the game? So there is a Start Button, a Exit Button, and when I click the Start only then the game starts. Please answer in simple terms if possible since I am a beginner. Thanks :)

---

Main.java

```
   import java.awt.Graphics;

   public class Main extends GameLoop {
/**
 * 
 */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


     public void init(){
       setSize(960,540);
       Thread th = new Thread(this);
       th.start();
       offscreen = createImage(960,540);
       c = offscreen.getGraphics();
       addKeyListener(this);
   }
   public void paint(Graphics g)
   {
    c.clearRect(0,0,960,480);
    c.drawImage(background, 0, 0, this);
    c.drawImage(mario, x, y, 100, 100, this);
    c.drawImage(goomba, ax, ay, 30, 30, this);
    c.drawImage(foreground, 0, 0 , this ); 
    c.drawImage(pipes, 0, 0, this);
    c.drawImage(block1, 0,  0, this);
    c.drawImage(block2, 0,  0, this);
    c.drawImage(block3, 0,  0, this);
    c.drawImage(block4, 0,  0, this);
    c.drawImage(block5, 0,  0, this);
    c.drawImage(block6, 0,  0, this);
    c.drawImage(block7 , 0, 0, this);
    //c.drawImage(blocks, 0, 0, this);
    g.drawImage(offscreen, 0 , 0 ,this);

}
@Override
public void update(Graphics g){
    paint(g);
}
```

}

---

GameLoop.java

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class GameLoop extends Applet implements Runnable, KeyListener {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public int x,y,ax,ay;
public Image offscreen;
public Graphics c;
public boolean jump,down,right,left;
public BufferedImage background, foreground, pipes, blocks, block1, block2,        block3, block4, block5, block6, block7,  walk2, walk3, walk4, walk5, walk6,   jumpR,jumpL, mario, goomba, deadMario, money, block;
public BufferedImage Bblock1, Bblock2, Bblock3;
public int wow;
public int wow2;
public double counter = 4;
public int MaxH, MidH, MinH, delta;




@Override
public void run() {
    x = 60;
    y = 440;
    ax = x +5;
    ay = 493;
    MinH = 440;


    try {
        background = ImageIO.read(new File("resources/background1.png"));
        foreground = ImageIO.read(new File("resources/foreground1.png"));
        blocks = ImageIO.read(new File("resources/blocks1.png"));
        pipes = ImageIO.read(new File("resources/pipes1.png"));
        walk2 = ImageIO.read(new File("resources/walk2.png"));
        walk3 = ImageIO.read(new File("resources/walk3.png"));
        walk4 = ImageIO.read(new File("resources/walk4.png"));
        walk5 = ImageIO.read(new File("resources/walk5.png"));
        walk6 = ImageIO.read(new File("resources/walk6.png"));
        jumpR = ImageIO.read(new File("resources/jumpR.png"));
        jumpL = ImageIO.read(new File("resources/jumpL.png"));
        goomba = ImageIO.read(new File("resources/goomba.gif"));
        deadMario = ImageIO.read(new File("resources/deadmario.png"));
        money = ImageIO.read(new File("resources/money.png"));
        block = ImageIO.read(new File("resources/Block.png"));
        block1 = ImageIO.read(new File("resources/block1.png"));
        block2 = ImageIO.read(new File("resources/block2.png"));
        block3 = ImageIO.read(new File("resources/block3.png"));
        block4 = ImageIO.read(new File("resources/block4.png"));
        block5 = ImageIO.read(new File("resources/block5.png"));
        block6 = ImageIO.read(new File("resources/blocks6.png"));
        block7 = ImageIO.read(new File("resources/block7.png"));
        Bblock1 = ImageIO.read(new File("resources/Bblock1.png"));
        Bblock2 = ImageIO.read(new File("resources/Bblock2.png"));
        Bblock3 = ImageIO.read(new File("resources/Bblock3.png"));
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    mario = walk2;
    while(true)
    {
        if (y <=440&& jump != true){
            y += 5;

        }
        if (y <=175){
            y = MinH;
        }

    if(ax != 475 && ax < 475){
        ax++;
    }
    if(ax >= 475 && ax != 60){
        ax = ax - 475;
        repaint();
    }
    if(x >= 468 && x <= 546){
        y=385;
    }
    if(x >= 736 && x <= 826){
        y=355;
    }

    if(x >= 160 && x <= 200 && y < 440 && y > 400){
        y = MinH;
            block1 = block; 

                }

    if(x >= 264 && x <= 338 && y < 440 && y > 400){
        y = MinH;
        block3 = Bblock1;
                }
    if(x >= 339 && x <=410 && y < 440 && y > 400){
        y = MinH;
        block5 = Bblock2;
                }

    if (block1 == block && y >=  440){
        c.drawImage(money, 210, 332,30,20, this);

    }
    if (block3 == Bblock1 && y >=  440){
        c.drawImage(money, 337, 332,30,30, this);

    }
    if (block5 == Bblock2 && y >=  440){
        c.drawImage(money, 395, 332,30,30, this);

    }




        wow++;
        wow2++;
        if(wow >= 20){
            wow = 0;
        }
        if(wow <= 5 && right == true){
            mario = walk2;
        }
        if(wow >= 5 && wow <=10 && right == true){
            mario = walk2;
        }
        if(wow <= 10 && wow >=5 && right == true){
            mario = walk5;
        }
        if(wow >= 10  && wow <=5 &&right == true){
            mario = walk2;
        }


        if(wow2 >= 20){
            wow2 = 0;
        }
        if(wow2 <= 5 && left == true){
            mario = walk3;
        }
        if(wow2 >= 5 && left == true){
            mario = walk6;
        }
        if(wow2 <= 10 && wow >=5 && left == true){
            mario = walk6;
        }
        if(wow2 >= 10  && wow <=5 && left == true){
            mario = walk3;
}   


    if(left == true){
        x-=2;

    }
    if(right == true){
        x+=2;

    }
    if(jump == true){
        counter += 0.1;
     y = y + (int) ((Math.sin(counter ) + Math.cos(counter))*15.5); 

    }
    if(counter == 7){
        counter = 4;
    }
    if(down == true){
        y+=2;

    }

if(y >= MinH ){
        y = MinH;
}

    System.out.println("(" + x + "," + y + ")");
    repaint();

    try {
        Thread.sleep(20);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

}


@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
// don't use

}


@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if(e.getKeyCode() == 37 ){
        left = true;
        }
    if(e.getKeyCode() == 38){
        jump = true;
        mario = jumpR;
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode() == 39){
        right = true;
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode() == 40){
        down = true;
    }

}


@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    if(e.getKeyCode() == 37){
        left = false;   
        mario = walk3;
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode() == 38){
        jump = false;
        mario = walk2;
        counter = 4;


    }
    if(e.getKeyCode() == 39){
        right = false;
        mario = walk2;
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode() == 40){
        down = false;
        mario = walk2;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `Applet` was superseded by `JApplet` 17+ years ago, but with the recent habit of browsers to actively block the applet plugin, and better solutions becoming available, it's not really advisable to use applets any more. Instead, you should base all your UI views on something like a `JPanel` instead, each view would be responsible for performing a given action (like a menu screen or the main game screen or whatever), then you could use a `CardLayout` to switch between them. By utilising `JPanel`s, you can then add these to what ever container you want, like a `JApplet` or `JFrame`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep up with states. For example you would have a START state and a RUNNING state. If the game is in the START state then you would draw the start screen, if it's in the RUNNING state you would draw your game. Later you may have a PAUSE state and a GAME_OVER state so you can show different screens there.

So to do this you will need a State enum like this:

```
public enum State
{
    START, RUNNING, PAUSE, GAME_OVER;
}
```

Then in your GameLoop class create a variable to hold the current state.

```
private State state = State.START;
```

Then in your draw code and anywhere else necessary you can check the current state variable and draw the appropriate screen.

```
public void run()
{
    switch(state)
    {
    case START:
        //DRAW THE START SCREEN
        break;
    case RUNNING:
        //DRAW THE GAME
        break;
    case PAUSE:
        //DRAW THE PAUSE SCREEN
        break;
    case GAME_OVER:
        //DRAW THE GAME OVER SCREEN
        break;
    default:
        throw new RuntimeException("Unknown state: " + state);
    }
}
```

A more clean solution would be to have a Screen class that has a draw method. Then your GameLoop just looks up the Screen associated with a given State and calls the draw method on it. This way your drawing code stays neatly tucked in to each Screen instead of all blobbed into one place. As your number of Screens grow you just add another Screen implementation. Here is some code to show what I mean:

Here is a Screen interface. You will have a Screen implementation for each State.

```
public interface Screen
{
    void update();
    void draw();
    void handleInput();
}
```

Here is an empty example of a RunningScreen.

```
public class RunningScreen implements Screen
{
    @Override
    public void update()
    {
        //UPDATE LOGIC, MOVE ENTITIES OR WHATEVER
    }

    @Override
    public void draw()
    {
        //DRAW THE RUNNING SCREEN
    }

    @Override
    public void handleInput()
    {
        //CHECK FOR USER INPUT AND UPDATE THE SCREEN STATE
    }

}
```

Here is an empty example of a StartScreen.

```
public class StartScreen implements Screen
{

    @Override
    public void update()
    {
        //UPDATE THE START SCREEN
    }

    @Override
    public void draw()
    {
        //DRAW THE START SCREEN
    }

    @Override
    public void handleInput()
    {
        //CHECK FOR INPUT, TRANSITION TO THE RUNNING SCREEN WHEN THE USER CLICKS START
    }

}
```

Your game loop looks up the Screen that is registered to handle the current state, then calls the appropriate methods.

```
public class GameLoop
{
    private State state = State.START;
    private Map<State, Screen> screens = new HashMap<>();

    public void addScreen(State state, Screen screen)
    {
        screens.put(state, screen);
    }

    public void run()
    {
        Screen screen = screens.get(state);
        screen.handleInput();
        screen.update();
        screen.draw();
    }
}
```

Then your Main might look something like this. It creates a new GameLoop and registers the Screens for each state.

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        GameLoop game = new GameLoop();
        game.addScreen(State.START, new StartScreen());
        game.addScreen(State.RUNNING, new RunningScreen());
        //Add other states here
        game.run();
    }
}
```

I hope this gives you some ideas about how to implement the functionality you want.

Comment: No problem. By the way, depending on how deep you want to get in to it, there are libraries that have these concepts built for you. Check out LibGDX. It's a java game framework that helps tremendously with this. A good game tutorial that shows you how to create Super Mario bros in LibGDX is here. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a8MPxzkwBwo. That guy also has a FlappyBird game tutorial. In that one he takes you through game states in detail.